# javascript: filter objects by multiple values with array using a functional approach

Tags: javascript, dictionary, filter, functional-programming, reduce

I am trying to search a list of objects using a list of values and a list of keys. My first approach is to create a list of objects given a particular value. However, the key is hard-coded and I should be using a more functional approach. Next, I think I should create a list of objects after filtering for each value. However, I am again hard-coding the values. I am not sure how to pass a list of values and a list of keys such as the following. Should I have used a Map object? if so, how can I extract the following two variables?:

```
const list_of_keys = ['color_1', 'color_2', 'color_3']
const list_of_values =  ['red','blue','purple']`
```

```
const data = [
    {make: 'ford',model: 'mustang',color_1: 'red',color_2: '',color_3: ''},
    {make: 'ford',model: 'escape',color_1: '',color_2: 'blue',color_3: ''},
    {make: 'ford',model: 'expedition',color_1: '',color_2: '',color_3: 'purple'},
    {make: 'mercedez',model: 'helicopter',color_1: '',color_2: '',color_3: 'orange'}
]

// hard-coded object keys
const filter_by_multiple_keys = (carObject, Value) => carObject.filter(car =>
    car.color_1 === Value ||
    car.color_2 === Value ||
    car.color_3 === Value
    );

// hard-coded values
const filterByColorsObject = list_of_objects => {

    const dataArray = [];

    dataArray.push(filter_by_multiple_keys(list_of_objects, 'red'));
    dataArray.push(filter_by_multiple_keys(list_of_objects, 'blue'));
    dataArray.push(filter_by_multiple_keys(list_of_objects, 'purple'));

    return(dataArray)

}

console.log(filterByColorsObject(data))
```

Answer (score 2):

Creating an array of the key names is the right idea - check if `.some` of them, when that property is accessed on the object, are equal to the value:

```
const filter_by_multiple_Columns = (carObject, value) => carObject.filter(
  car => list_of_keys.some(
    key => car[key] === value
  )
);
```

To construct multiple columns, `.map` from the `list_of_values` array:

```
const filterByColorsObject = list_of_objects => list_of_values.map(
  value => filter_by_multiple_Columns(list_of_objects, value)
);
```

But this is an extremely strange data structure. If at all possible, change the `colors` properties to an *array*, instead of multiple separate properties:

```
{ make: 'mercedez',model: 'helicopter', colors: ['', '', 'orange'] }
```

or

```
{ make: 'mercedez',model: 'helicopter',colors: ['orange'] }
```

This would make them much easier to iterate over. For the above, you would do:

```
const filter_by_multiple_Columns = (carObject, Value) => carObject.filter(
  car => car.colors.includes(Value)
);
```

Comment: That's a good point. I shall fix my data structure. Thank you!

Comment: What's interesting about your filter_by_multiple_Columns function @CertainPerformance, is that it returns three lists in this case. I am assuming one for each item on the list. Is there a clean way you would recommend to merge the three lists? Thank you

Comment: That's the same thing your original `filterByColorsObject` was doing - you created an array and pushed an array to it 3 times, so I thought that's what you wanted. If you want all items to be collected into a single array, use `.flatMap` instead of `.map` for `filterByColorsObject`, so the results get flattened.

Comment: Another suggestion, if you don't mind - it would probably be a lot easier to read and write if one follows the usual convention of always using `camelCase` for ordinary variables, rather than using mixed styles (resulting in having to double check which style and casing the variable is using every time)

Comment: Thank you, this is much appreciated. I'll keep my styles consistent too.

Comment: When an answer solves your problem, you may consider marking it as Accepted (check the checkbox on the left) to indicate that the issue is resolved :)